# Undefined Value on Itunes search Api

Tags: json, itunes

I have this HTML and Js and the firtst result is an undefined value.
I want to remove that undefined Value.

I know its a simple solution but i cant fugure it out.
I ask for help please..
Thank you.

**Custom. js**

```
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
         url: "--URL--",
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         success: function(json_results){
         console.log(json_results);

         $('#twitList').append('<ul data-role="listview"></ul>');
         listItems = $('#twitList').find('ul');
         $.each(json_results.results, function(key) {
                html = '<img src="'+json_results.results[key].artworkUrl60+'"/>';
                html += '<h3><a href="#">'+json_results.results[key].collectionName+'</a></h3>';
                html += '<p>From: '+json_results.results[key].artistName+'</p>';
                html += '<p>Created: '+json_results.results[key].releaseDate+'</p>';
                listItems.append('<li>'+html+'</li>');
                });
         // Need to refresh list after AJAX call
         $('#twitList ul').listview();
         }
         });
  })
```

**HTML**

```
    <title>Itunes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

    <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Itunes</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">

            <div id="twitList"></div>


        </div><!-- /content -->

    </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:

```
$(function(){
     $.ajax({
         url: "--URL--",
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         success: function(json_results){
         console.log(json_results);

         $('#twitList').append('<ul data-role="listview"></ul>');
         listItems = $('#twitList').find('ul');

         $.each(json_results.results, function(key) {

            // edit
            var data = json_results.results[key],
                artworkUrl60 = data.artworkUrl60 || '',
                collectionName = data.collectionName || '',
                artistName = data.artistName || '',
                releaseDate = data.releaseData || '';

            html = '<img src="' + artworkUrl60 + '"/>';
            html += '<h3><a href="#">' + collectionName + '</a></h3>';
            html += '<p>From: ' + artistName + '</p>';
            html += '<p>Created: ' + releaseDate + '</p>';
            listItems.append('<li>' + html + '</li>');
         });

         // Need to refresh list after AJAX call
         $('#twitList ul').listview();
     }
 });
```

})

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer.But it doesnt work. it still gives me an undefined value on the first line.

Comment: use firebug to see the response json, and paste it plz.

Comment: This is the URL:
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=262268554&entity=album&limit=1&sort=recent

Comment: I limited to "1" so i can see all the albuns of my client. but doing that search it gives me 2 results, being the first the artist information... and in the html and my script it "thinks" that has some value and gives me an undefined..

Comment: Hello. Could you be kind if you "paste" the code that i must use, because i dont know how to start, like where do i place the "var" element.. Thank you so mutch..

Answer (score 0):

I got this running (fixes undefined value on the first line) by whitelisiting *.phobos.apple.com. and using your exact code.